# How to join one table with two different tables with similar fields in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 3 tables in BigQuery.
I need to join first one (contains ids), to others (contains list of values for ids). I want to have sum of values by ids from two tables:

```
SELECT t0.id, sum(values) FROM t0
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t0.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t0.id = t2.id
GROUP BY id
```

It does not work with an error `Column name values is ambiguous`
What is the best way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t0.id, sum(t1.values) + sum(t2.values) as sumOfValues FROM t0
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t0.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t0.id = t2.id
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below better reflect your original idea

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, sum(u.values) 
FROM t0
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, values FROM t1 UNION ALL
  SELECT id, values FROM t2
) u
USING (id)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It was my first idea but I looked for the "best" way to make it better especially by running time. I don't know details of theory how it works but I think `UNION` statement runs slowly than double join. Maybe I'm wrong because I don't have any evidence in it. Do you know why `UNION` works slowly or it is just myth?

Comment: in my mind - at least in simple case like yours above  - UNION is cheaper and more optimal than extra JOIN(s) - you can compare execution plan/stats for both approaches and see result.  Would be great to know result of your analysis on real data. Meantime, I still feel that approach with UNION is "preferred" here